# Wait 5 days for a user to tick a button on an infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, designer-workflow

I am looking for a solution in SharePoint designer workflow, which will wait 5 days for the user to select a tickbox in an infopath form. If the user ticks before 5 days then all good (it will then need to carry on with the rest of the workflow) else if it is passed 5 days then it will carry on with the workflow (but without the tickbox being ticked.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the workflow steps below:

[image]

Change the “Log to history list” action in the above step with your rest of workflow steps.